# Overloading WinMain() function while using Unicode character set

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode, winmain

How can i overload the `WinMain()` function while using Unicode character set in Visual Studio? Thank you.

[Here's the code i am talking about](http://hotfile.com/dl/139104453/a73183a/GI.Graphics.Programming.DirectX.9.Module.I-Source.Code.rar.html)

Comment: Overload `WinMain()`? what? why? That seems Bad.

Comment: im trying to write a game engine, and, as far as i know, its a common practice.

Comment: For what purpose? What do you want to do? I can think of no practical use for this, considering it's called only once as the entry point. Maybe you're looking for `_tWinMain` which is the TCHAR version in case you want to compile as either Unicode or ANSI char?

Comment: Use wWinMain(), _tWinMain() is from the previous century.

Comment: @Abdulali: The common practice is to declare `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)` and `#define`ing `UNICODE` before `#include`ing `windows.h` if you want to work with Unicode. There's no need to write separate non-Unicode and Unicode `WinMain()`s, and you can't anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no point in overloading WinMain, this function is called only once at startup. If you want it to work in UNICODE and non UNICODE builds then you should make suse that it will accept wchar_t* and char* for pszCmdLine parameter:

```
int WINAPI _tWinMain(
   HINSTANCE hInstanceExe,
   HINSTANCE,
   PTSTR pszCmdLine,
   int nCmdShow);
```

Comment: I know it CAN be overloaded. That is why i posted this question.

Comment: @Abdulali : No, it can't. The Unicode entry point is named `wWinMain`; you can't overload two functions with different names. The `_tWinMain` merely expands to `WinMain` or `wWinMain` according to whether or not the `UNICODE` macro is defined.

Comment: I have working code with overloaded `WinMain()` function that works perfectly well. However once i import it into VS2010, it crashes. Ive looked it up on MSDN and found out that the reason is the `lpCmdLine` parameter of the WinMain(). however MSDN provides no sample code.

Comment: what is yours WinMain, lpCmdLine parameter type?

Comment: its parameter type is `LPSTR`

Comment: @Abdulali : If it crashes, then how does it "work perfectly well"?

Comment: change it to PTSTR, LPSTR results always to CHAR *, and on UNICODE you want WCHAR*. PTSTR will be CHAR* on non-UNICODE, and WCHAR* on UNICODE builds.

Comment: @luskan i just tried it, still wont compile. gives me error `C2731: 'WinMain' : function cannot be overloaded` again

Comment: probably you have WinMain duplicate somewhere in your code, or in any libraries you are including

Comment: @Abdulali You're getting that error because it's not possible to overload WinMain. There can only be one.

Comment: "I know it CAN be overloaded".  What makes you think that, exactly?  Provide more details.

Comment: no, i have no duplicates. just function member that catches: `(HANDLE hInstance, LPCTSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow)`.

Comment: you are missing one HINSTANCE, as second parameter

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - TeamB  http://www.gameinstitute.com/courses.php?coursedisplay=49. the code is in this book.

Comment: @Abdulali: No one here is willing to pay $215.00 just to verify what you read. And when writing questions on Stack Overflow in the future, just paste the code in the question and not link it to some kind of file dropbox service.

Comment: @Abdulali: And I don't see any `WinMain()` "overloading" in the code you provided, so I don't even understand the premise of your question. The point still stands, you can't have two `WinMain()` functions, even if they have different names. The way you write a `WinMain()` function is to have a function [with this exact signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559.aspx) (ignore the `__in`s), and if you want Unicode you define `UNICODE` before including `windows.h`. That's it.

Comment: If they have different names (like `WinMain()` and `wWinMain()` do), then by definition they are not overloads of each other.  Overloads must have exact same name, and they have to both exist in the executable at the same time (`WinMain()` and `wWinMain()` do not coexist - an app has one or the other, not both).